# Unexplained margin at top of page

Tags: html, css

On my client's website [opcstm.org](http://opcstm.org/) every browser I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer) renders a margin of about 16px at the top of each page except the homepage.

For example, compare the homepage to the [Contact Us page](http://opcstm.org/contact-us-2/). On the Contact Us page you will see that the logo, the entire header element, and the entire page is separated from the top of the browser window by about 16x of margin.

I've used browser developer tools to inspect the first three elements in the HTML code (body, div.site-container, header.site-header) and none of them have top margin or top padding specified.

I'm stumped! Can you help?

Comment: Can you please post code, especially CSS in this case? It is hard to figure things out using the dev tools

Comment: You've got a strange empty p.title in the header block which obviously pushes the header down.

Comment: Please post your CSS and HTML code

Answer (score 1):

The id of title (p in the header) is your issue. Remove it or give it a margin: 0;

```
#title {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix you could just add style="padding-top:16px" to your `<div class="wrap">`

for example: `<div style="padding-top:16px" class="wrap">`

I would not recommend doing this every time. This should be used as a temporary fix until you find the problem.